# how to fetch complete row while comparing two files by using python or shell

Tags: python, linux

`unique.txt` file contains: 2 columns with columns separated by tab.
`total.txt` file contains: 3 columns each column separated by tab.

I take each row from `unique.txt` file and find that in `total.txt` file.
If present then extract entire row from `total.txt` and save it in new output file.

```
###Total.txt
column a        column b                    column c
interaction1    mitochondria_205000_225000  mitochondria_195000_215000
interaction2    mitochondria_345000_365000  mitochondria_335000_355000
interaction3    mitochondria_345000_365000  mitochondria_5000_25000
interaction4    chloroplast_115000_128207   chloroplast_35000_55000
interaction5    chloroplast_115000_128207   chloroplast_15000_35000
interaction15   2_10515000_10535000 2_10505000_10525000

###Unique.txt
column a                    column b
mitochondria_205000_225000  mitochondria_195000_215000
mitochondria_345000_365000  mitochondria_335000_355000
mitochondria_345000_365000  mitochondria_5000_25000
chloroplast_115000_128207   chloroplast_35000_55000
chloroplast_115000_128207   chloroplast_15000_35000
mitochondria_185000_205000  mitochondria_25000_45000
2_16595000_16615000 2_16585000_16605000
4_2785000_2805000   4_2775000_2795000
4_11395000_11415000 4_11385000_11405000
4_2875000_2895000   4_2865000_2885000
4_13745000_13765000 4_13735000_13755000
```

Comment: What did you try so far? you may want to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking a question.

Comment: I tryied it in the way #!/bin/bash
FILE=$1
while read line; do
     egrep  "$line" Total.txt >> new_out.txt
done < $unique.txt

Comment: I tryied it in the way

Comment: You tried it without python I see? Could you also please clarify in your question What is a column? Its not clear with your formatting. i.e. name them `column a`, `column b`, etc.

Comment: in Total.txt column a, column b and column c. In unique.txt coulmn q and coulmn b.

Comment: Please edit your question with it... You cannot expect the users here to do everything for you

Comment: Added an aswer which solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do the trick.

```
import csv
total = "C:\\...total.txt" #set path to your file!
unique = "C:\\...unique.txt"
newfile = "C:\\...match.csv"

a = []
b = []
towrite = []

with open(total, "r") as rcursor1: #read the document
    for trow in rcursor1: #read each row
        row1 = trow.split("\t") #split it by your seperator
        a.append(row1[1:]) #we are only interested in everything from column b onwards


with open(unique, "r") as rcursor2:
    for urow in rcursor2:
        row2 = urow.split("\t")
        b.append(row2)


print "This is a", a
print len(a)
print "This is b", b
print len(b)

a1 = set(map(tuple, a)) #lists are hashable, but we need unhasable object to work with set
b1 = set(map(tuple, b)) #that why change list to tuples, tuples are not hashable

matches = set(a1).intersection(b1) #find the matches, best is to take shorter list as first argument for better perfomance!
print "Our matches, unsorted!", matches

with open(newfile, 'wb') as wcursor: #write to file
    for i in matches:
        c = list(i)
        d = ",".join(c)
        print d
        wcursor.write(str(d)+"\n")
```

Comment: 'file=open('total.txt')
file2 = open('unique.txt')
all_content=file.readlines()
all_content2=file2.readlines()
store_id_lines = []
for i in range(len(all_content)):
 line=all_content[i].split('\t')
  #now you don't need first column so you can do 
seq=line[1]+'\t'+line[2]
  # compare ith line of unique.txt with ith line (column 2nd 3) of total.txt
 if all_content2 [i]==seq [i]
 ## if condition is correct then open file and write complete row into out .dat
x = open('out.dat', 'w')
ff.write(store_id_lines.append(seq (i)))
 # match this seq to your unique.txt
'

Comment: What do you mean with that. Please give more information... A few sentencens or something

Comment: @user2560507 you need to give more information than that

Comment: @user2560507 did you copy paste my codesnippet 1 to 1?

Comment: yes Sir  I just copied your sytax and past it and run it.

Comment: @user2560507 it worked for me. What python are you using? You may want to replace the map function with a generator...

Answer (score 0):

here is my python script

```
enter code here`file=open('total.txt')

file2 = open('unique.txt')
all_content=file.readlines()
all_content2=file2.readlines()
store_id_lines = []
ff = open('match.dat', 'w')

for i in range(len(all_content)):
              line=all_content[i].split('\t')
              seq=line[1]+'\t'+line[2]
              for j in range(len(all_content2)):
                     if all_content2[j]==seq:
                           ff.write(seq)
                           break
```

but istide of giving desire output (values of those 1st column that fulfile the if condition).
i nead somthing like if jth of unique.txt == ith of total.txt
then write ith row of total.txt into new file